# При вводе числа в переменную num выдает ошибку ValueEror

Tags: python

Я решил посмотреть, что вводится в переменную num. Оказалось, что вводится '', хотя я его не ввожу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так. P.s. ошибка выходит, когда я ставлю int перед input

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Признаю, ваш код у меня работает как и должен. Эта проблема точно не в коде. Попробуйте запустить скрипт с обычной консоли cmd. Консоль пайчарма иногда шалит.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)